# Find the triple integral $\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2(x+y+z)}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\sin z dxdydz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$\int_{x^2+y^2+z^2\le 2(x+y+z)}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\sin z dxdydz$

Can you give me a hint how to start?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

The "interval" you are given to integrate over is a sphere. Observe, that :

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 2(x + y + z) $$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2 - 2y + 1 + z^2 - 2z + 1 -3 \leq 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 \leq 3$$

Comment: Yes, but it looks bad when I change it to spherical coordinates(

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by Masacroso, a suitable intgration is over a sphere of radius $\surd 3$
centered at (1,1,1),
so the spherical coordinates would be
$x=1+\rho \cos\phi \sin\theta$,
$y=1+\rho \sin\phi \sin\theta$,
$z=1+\rho \cos\theta$.
The Jacobian is the familiar $\sin\theta \rho^2$, because a shift
of the center does not modify the partial derivatives in the coordinate transformation.
$$
I=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho (x^2+y^2+z^2)\sin z
$$
$$
=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho
\sin(1+\rho\cos\theta)[3+2\rho \cos\phi\sin\theta+2\rho\sin\phi\sin\theta+\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta]
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_0^\pi \sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho                 
\sin(1+\rho\cos\theta)[3+\rho^2+2\rho\cos\theta].
$$
Substitution $\cos\theta=u$, $du=-\sin\theta d\theta$:
$$
I=-2\pi \int_1^{-1} du \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho             
\sin(1+\rho u)[3+\rho^2+2\rho u].
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_{-1}^{1} du \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho
\sin(1+\rho u)[3+\rho^2+2\rho u].
$$
$$
=2\pi \int_0^{\sqrt 3}\rho^2 d\rho               
\frac{1}{\rho}[
(3+\rho^2-2\rho)\cos(\rho-1)
+2\sin(\rho-1)
+(-3-\rho^2-2\rho)\cos(\rho+1)
+2\sin(\rho+1)
]
$$
$$
=24\pi [ \sin 1 \sin\surd 3-\surd 3\cos 1 \cos\surd 3]
$$